# Can you set a default console region in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, admin, default

I am setting up an account for a small organization and I decided to isolate the master account and create an admin IAM user. I set up the database and follow the tutorial to create an admin IAM user. I log in to the admin account later to verify everything looks good and don't see any services including the RDS instance. I go through the pain of verifying all of the details in the tutorials and more.

Turns out my console was just on a different region then the master account's console.

Seems like there ought to be either 1) a console view of all resources (across all regions so a true all resources view) OR 2) an ability to set a default console region.

Either of these would enable one to have a bit more sanity during management of their setup.

Comment: You can bookmark a URL that takes you to a specific service within a specific region. Sometimes the console gets confused about the region when using 'global' service pages like Route 53, IAM and Amazon S3.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for the idea. Seems like a limited user interface that causes a lot of newbie headache IMHO.

Comment: comment by @JohnRotenstein helped - i had erroneously bookmarked the wrong region and wondered why kept 'defaulting' to it

Comment: Make a habit of setting the region first-thing after signing in.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

tl;dr: No. If you've logged into an account before, your browser caches the last region you were in for each service.

When you login to a new account the region isn't cached so it usually (service dependent) loads the us-east-1 / us-west-2 page.

+1000 for being able to set up a default console region either in the account, or in the AWS Organization for each sub-account/OU/the whole organization.

You can do it in the CLI, so why not the console? Seems like an easy feature add.

There's an old doc on it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/console-help-gsg.pdf

Edit: This isn't just an issue for newbies, it would save a lot of mini heart attacks when people log in to an account and think they're missing resources, only to find out they're in the wrong region!

Comment: Doesn't use cached region for me! Keeps defaulting to Oregon even when I switch to N. California. Every time, seriously.

Comment: Yeah we use RBAC and I can't bookmark. Another mind boggling miss by AWS.

Comment: "this isn't just an issue for newbies". Been using AWS for a decade and this still trips me up

Comment: It is currently possible.

Answer (score 23):

According to the recent announcement by AWS, it is now possible to have a preferred/default region set. Read more here:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/04/unified-settings-aws-management-console/

Comment: Tested it and it works just fine, so voting up! Instead of adding another response with a screenshot, I added a screenshot to the edit queue for this answer. Hopefully someone will approve it.

Comment: It was difficult to find since it's not in the default 'settings'.  However, it also does not work reliably; at least when switching accounts, it regularly reverts back to the old crap.

Comment: this worked for me. i was able to switch my default region with this step, thanks

Comment: The UI is extremely laborious to navigate unfortunately and seems to have changed since that doc came out. 

I found the settings page at https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/settings/home?region=us-east-2#/

Answer (score 8):

To expand on Sudhanshu's answer, you can now change you're preferred region in the **Settings** from the top right dropdown...

[image: Settings dropdown]

Then **Edit** the **Localisation** section...

[image: Localisation]

Notice it's usually set to *Last used region*...

[image: Setting the region]

Answer (score 1):

Execute in the console:

```
aws configure set default.region us-east-2
```